# Overriding member in Backbone views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js to manage my views. I extend Backbone.View like so:

```
My.Views.PieChart = Backbone.View.extend({
    chartId: '',
    plot: {},
    params: {},
    legendLocation: 's',    // default value
    ...
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.legendLocation);
    }
});
```

Then I extend PieChart again to get the specific object.

```
My.Views.GenderChart = My.Views.PieChart.extend({
    chartId: 'gender',
    el: '#gender',
    legendPosition: 'e'
});
```

However, the GenderChart.legendPosition was still 's' when I call GenderChart.render()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain? Looks to me like the variables are two different names, and that might be causing the trouble. Do you actually want `legendLocation` and `legendPosition` or do you want to be overriding the `legendLocation` key in the superclass?

Comment: Jesus, of course I meant legendLocation. Thanks for spotting the mistake!